# Mobile App Authentication, Active Directory, Intranet API

Tags: .net, mobile, active-directory

An interesting request came across my desk, and I needed some help to figure out the details.

Our facilities department needs a bar code scanning application that can lookup different pieces of equipment (water heaters, AC units, etc.) in our database while they are moving around campus.  They would like to make sure that only people within the Facilities department can use this application.

I have used the bar code scanner API in Ioncic and Xamarin before, so I should be able to use either one to set-up the bar code scanning.

I can easily set-up an API with integrated security, and limit it to our facilities department.

The main problem I am having is integrating a Client into Active Directory.  Is there a best practices for authenticating different clients into a .NET environment?

Comment: You can search about `ADFS` over the Internet. It'll get you started how to integrate your client with Active Directory for authentication and other purpose.

Comment: Thanks!  That was the push in the right direction.  Now I just need to talk to my network engineer.